# filled with zeros

Tags: qt, fill

How can I fill with zeros at left? My code is:

```
QString reelId = QString("Month %1").arg(QDate::currentDate().month());
qDebug() << reelId;
```

and out is: Month 2 and I want Month 02;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're really looking for is "pad", as in padding a string with something. Look through the QString documentation for this, specifically the various QString::arg() functions, which describes how to achieve this in a variety of ways :)

Comment: Thanks whith QString("Month %1")..arg(QDate::currentDate().month(), 2, 10, QChar('0')); work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [QString::rightJustified()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#rightJustified)

Answer (score 1):

```
QString reelId = QString( "Month %1" ).arg(
    QString::number( QDate::currentDate().month() ).rightJustified( 2, '0' )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another useful trick is to use QDate's toString() method thus:

```
QString reelId = QDate::currentDate().toString( "'Month' MM" );
```

The single quotes around "Month" prevent the word being interpreted as a placeholder.